# Apollo client TypeError: value.subscribe is not a function

Tags: javascript, next.js, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to use `BatchHttpLink` to batch requests from apollo on a `nextjs` application using below config:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';
import { ApolloProvider, ApolloClient, ApolloLink, from } from '@apollo/client'; 
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error'; 
import { BatchHttpLink } from '@apollo/client/link/batch-http';

const batchHttpLink = new BatchHttpLink({
    uri: process.env.GRAPHQL_URL,
    batchMax: 5,
    batchInterval: 20,
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    fetch
});

  /**
   * to parse batch call response
   * See more https://spectrum.chat/apollo/apollo-client/batchhttplink-not-working-with-usequery-react-hooks~3eeb6635-c5a8-4b8a-a2fd-3b7fbebc5816
   */
  const parseBatchResponseMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) =>
    forward(operation).map((data: any) => data.payload)
  );

  const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, forward, operation }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors) {
      console.warn(graphQLErrors);
    }
    if (networkError) {
      console.warn(networkError);
    }
    forward(operation);
  });

  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link: from([parseBatchResponseMiddleware, errorLink, authLink.concat(batchHttpLink)]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
      possibleTypes: introspectionToPossibleTypes(introspectionQueryResultData)
    })
  });
```

I added `parseBatchResponseMiddleware` to parse the batch response. When I run app on development mode everything seems correct but as soon as I build app on prod environment it returns 500-internal server error:

> TypeError: value.subscribe is not a function
> at Object.complete (/.../node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/observables/Concast.js:57:43)
> at Concast.start (/.../node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/observables/Concast.js:83:23)
> at new Concast (/.../node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/observables/Concast.js:75:19)
> at QueryManager.getObservableFromLink (/.../node_modules/@apollo/client/core/QueryManager.js:551:35)
> at QueryManager.getResultsFromLink (/.../node_modules/@apollo/client/core/QueryManager.js:590:30)
> at resultsFromLink (/.../node_modules/@apollo/client/core/QueryManager.js:755:26)
> at QueryManager.fetchQueryByPolicy (/.../node_modules/@apollo/client/core/QueryManager.js:782:21)
> at fromVariables (/.../node_modules/@apollo/client/core/QueryManager.js:638:26)
> at QueryManager.fetchQueryObservable (/.../node_modules/@apollo/client/core/QueryManager.js:645:15)
> at QueryManager.fetchQuery (/.../node_modules/@apollo/client/core/QueryManager.js:260:21)
> at QueryManager.query (/.../node_modules/@apollo/client/core/QueryManager.js:345:21)
> at ApolloClient.query (/.../node_modules/@apollo/client/core/ApolloClient.js:133:34)
> at Function.Z.t.getInitialProps (/.../src/.next/server/pages/_app.js:158:151526)
> at Function.B.r.getInitialProps (/.../src/.next/server/pages/_app.js:158:147992)

Any ideas to solve this issue is highly appreciated.